# How to apply style to matched text with Quill.js

Tags: quill

I'm using Quill.js and trying to apply custom formatting to text that matches a specific pattern.

For example, I want to match anything between curly braces `{ ... }`.

I'm listening for the 'text-change' event and matching the inserted text:

```js
quillRef.current.on('text-change', (delta, oldDelta, source) => {
          delta.forEach((op) => {
            if (!quillRef.current) return
            if (typeof op.insert === 'string') {
              const matches = op.insert.match(tagRegex)

              if (matches) {
                const matchIndex = matches.index
                const matchLength = matches[0].length

                matchIndex &&
                  quillRef.current.formatText(matchIndex, matchLength, ['bold'])
              }
            }
          })
        })
```

For now I'm trying to just bold everything {typed like this} and later on I want to give it a custom format (to give it bg color).

Some things I've tried:

```
Modifying the insert op directly
Using attributes or split to insert as separate op
Composing a new delta
```

But these approaches end up either styling all the text or causing duplicates.

What is the right way to selectively style only the matched text when reacting to text changes in Quill?